Implementing java SMTP client with only cert/private key based authentication
We have a need to create SMTP client which will be authorized by public/private key.My code looks like below, but server is not seeing the cert being passed and rejecting the request. can someone help me with the correct implementation? I have imported both public and private and created keystore.p12 file using openssl command: openssl pkcs12 -export -out keystore.p12 -inkey private.key -in public.crt -name "test"
 Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "test.test.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
        props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.protocols", "TLSv1.2");

        try {
            // Load the keystore
            KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
            keyStore.load(this.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("keystore.p12"), "password".toCharArray());

            // Create a MailSSLSocketFactory and set the keystore
            MailSSLSocketFactory socketFactory = new MailSSLSocketFactory();
            KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
            keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore, "password".toCharArray());
            socketFactory.setKeyManagers(keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers());
            //socketFactory.setKeyStorePassword("password");

            // Set the socket factory
            props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.socketFactory", socketFactory);

            Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);
            session.setDebug(true);
            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("test@test.com"));
            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                    new InternetAddress("test1@test1.com", false));
            message.setSubject("Testing Subject");
            message.setText("Test Mail");

            Transport.send(message);
            System.out.println("Done");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


(1) Mail Server needs to enable Require Client SSL Certificate. (2) Because your Client SSL certificate is self-signed, Mail Server needs to import your self-signed SSL certificate into the Mail Server's trust store.

mail server has the client cert already, and the functionality has been working thru python script. now we are converting it into java based.
